# Design pattern - creating an object from different types of data source

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have been trying to find an appropriate design pattern, if a formal one exists, for the following scenario:

Object A requires an object B. Now, object B can be created using data from different sources, say S_1 or S_2. I don't want A to have to care about creating B, it should just be given it and proceed. So then, is there a nice clean way of creating B? I have thought about factory-type patterns but I do not have polymorphism at play. I was thinking something like:

```
B obj_b = B.createInstance(type_S_1);
obj_A.doSomething(obj_B);
```

where I give the type of data soruce to the static method createInstance().

I'm still learning a lot about design patterns, so that's why I ask. I may be over complicating things, so please feel free to say so!

Comment: B is always of the same class? How does B change when `createInstance()` is given different sources?

Comment: B is always the same. The only difference is the source of data used to construct it.

Comment: What are the sources? Which types of simple data or class? Who decides which source apply? The class A? Are the only sources that are anticipated in the design, or will be adding more in the future? If you describe us better design can help you. From what you tell us, perhaps not worth seek a pattern. Sometimes simple is better.

Answer (score 2):

As you realized, the Abstract Factory pattern is overkill for your use case as you do not need polymorphism. Still, the Concrete Factory part of this design pattern make sense. So this could look a bit like:

```
Datasource ds1 = ...;
Datasource ds2 = ...;

MyObject objectA = ...;

DatasourceBasedFactory factory1 = new DatasourceBasedFactory(ds1);
objectA.doSomething(factory1.create());
```

Knowing more about what you actually want to do might help to give you a better answer. Your current problem description is extremely abstract ... If you could give us some more details about your domain, that would help to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but perhaps the [Builder Pattern?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) You can give it a type to specify what to build.

Comment: Builder implies an object built in part and a Director controlling the build process. Probably not a complete match for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider 2 differents approaches using generics.
The client will only deal with a common result Object that could be *final* for example.
No matter what your DataSource is, you can reduce the impact for the client.

**Approach 1**

*Example*

```
public interface DataSourceExtractor<T> {
     public DataSourceExtractResult extract(T source);
}

public final ResultSetExtractor implements DataSourceExtractor<ResultSet>{
     public DataSourceExtractResult extract(ResulSet source) {
       //CODE HERE        
       return null;
     }
}

public final ResultSetExtractor implements DataSourceExtractor<JsonNode>{
     public DataSourceExtractResult extract(JsonNode source) {
       //CODE HERE
       return null;
     }
}
```

But you can also meet the advantage of Abstract Class and Interface.
The advantage is that the client will inherit common methods or you can even implement template methods.

*Example*

```
public AbstractDataSourceExtractor<T> implements DataSourceExtractor<T> {

   public static final SomeObject commonMethod(DataSourceExtractResult result) {
      //CODE HERE
      return null;
    }

}

        public final ResultSetExtractor extends AbstractDataSourceExtractor<ResultSet>{
     public DataSourceExtractResult extract(ResulSet source) {
       //CODE HERE
       return null;
     }
}

public final ResultSetExtractor extends AbstractDataSourceExtractor<JsonNode>{
     public DataSourceExtractResult extract(JsonNode source) {
       //CODE HERE
       return null;
     }
}
```

**Approach 2**

*Example*

You can also think about a generic Abstract builder, if many elements need to be set for the construction of the Instance. 
The advatange of that solution is that you can set a default value, provide internal implementation hiding from the client if necessary.

```
public abstract class AbstractDataSourceExtractResultBuilder<T>{

    private T _source;

    public AbstractDataSourceExtractResultBuilder(T source) {
      _source = source;
    }


    public abstract DataSourceExtractResult  build();

}

public final class JsonDataSourceExtractBuilder extends AbstractDataSourceExtractResultBuilder<JsonNode> {

    private String _name;
    private Charset _charset;

   public JsonDataSourceExtractBuilder(JsonNode source, String name){
       //GUARD CODE
       super(source);
       _name = name;
       _charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
   }

   public JsonDataSourceExtractBuilder useCharset(Charset charset){
        if(charset == null){
         throw new IllegalStateException("The charset is null");
        }
        _charset = charset;
        return this;
   }

   //etc...

   public DataSourceExtractResult  build(){
     //CODE HERE
     return null;
   }

}
```